# What is a .meta file and why does Unity create them for all of my assets?

Tags: file, unity-game-engine, meta

For example, I might have Script.cs, but I would also have Script.cs.meta, or a folder named Sprites and a file named Sprites.meta. Why?

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ExternalVersionControlSystemSupport.html

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Well, meta fields are used to describe or specify a file, in version control too, but in unity meta files store the import settings of the files you have in your project. Your script or folder have a meta file which tells Unity how to prepare the asset in the project. If you delete a meta file Unity reimports the asset and creates the default meta file for that file type

Comment: Should I push meta files to version control or each machine should have their own meta files?

Comment: @A.v Sync them too. Unity stores the guid in them. When Unity can't find the meta files, it creates new ones with different guids which will lead to missing behaviour errors.